# Google Play vanished after uninstalling updates from Samsung Galaxy Note 2

Tags: google-play-store, updates, google

I was following advice that was supposed to help Google play work better. It said to go to the app and uninstall the updates and clear the cache. This I did but now Google Play is no where to be seen. It is not under Market or any other thing that even remotely resembles a store. I still have Google play music and Google play games but no Google play. I am no longer able to purchase in app items due to this and so far (over three days) it hasn't updated itself either. I have gone through everything including the tabs all and turned off. It just isn't there any more. Does anyone know what they may have called the original app? If its market then its gone as well. It is like it actually deleted it instead of just uninstalling the updates. I do not want to reboot the phone into its original settings as I don't know some of the passwords that I have set up for games and other things. It would take forever to track everything down.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting an apk of Google Play store for your android version (Available [here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/)) and install it as you normally do.

Note: If you have never installed an app outside from the google play store then you have to enable Install from unknown sources in the settings. After installing the app, turn this setting off.